# SQL query to return amount of sales and amount of salespersons

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

4am here... this is driving me nuts. I have a report table:

- id_report
- invoice_date
- id_user (sales person)

I need to display, by month, how many items were sold, and also how many salespersons sold those items. For example, in january user 3 sold 10 items and user 8 sold 7 items, that should return:

```
date    | items | salespersons
2014-01 | 17    | 2
```

This was my first approach, but that doesn't bring me the 3rd column:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%Y-%m") AS date, COUNT(*) AS items,  
FROM report
GROUP BY date
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you haven't add the third column. Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%Y-%m") AS date, 
COUNT(*) AS items,
COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) AS salespersons
FROM report 
GROUP BY date
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03e45/1

Comment: hardly, still a few more reports to finish. deadline in 3 hours :s

Comment: just in case you want to [give me one more hand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348673/mysql-getting-sum-of-balance-grouped-by-users-job-location) :s Im kind of desperate in here hehe

Answer (score 1):

It's important to use the `DISTINCT` keyword, or you will have the same count as items.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, '%Y-%m') AS date, 
  COUNT(*) AS items, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) as sales_persons 
FROM report 
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `count( id_user ) as sales_persons`.
This is not being selected.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%Y-%m") AS date, 
  COUNT(*) AS items, 
  count( id_user ) as sales_persons 
FROM report 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: tried that, but the sales_persons returns the exact amount as items, and it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking for the third column in your query. Add `COUNT(id_user) as salespersons`. Do your query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%Y-%m") AS date, COUNT(*) AS items, COUNT(id_user) as salespersons FROM report GROUP BY date
```

Comment: that works if i add DISTINCT in the id_user COUNT as suggested by @Aziz Shaikh