# MySQL getting SUM of balance grouped by user's job location

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join

Im trying to get the SUM of all user balances in a specific month, and grouped by the user's region, which depends on the Point of Sell they work at.

**balance**

- id_balance
- date
- id_user
- value ($$$)

**user**

- id_user
- id_pos
- name (*not relevant*)

**pos** (Point of Sell)

- id_pos
- id_region
- name (*not relevant*)

**location_region**

- id_region
- name (Florida, Texas, etc)

Basically, I would need it to present this data (filtered by month):

```
location_region.name | SUM(balance.value)
---------------------|-------------------
Florida              | 45730
Texas                | 43995
```

I've tried a few approaches with no luck. This was my closest attempt.

```
SELECT location_region.name, SUM(balance.value) AS money
FROM balance
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id_user
LEFT JOIN pos ON pos.id_pos = user.id_pos
LEFT JOIN location_region ON location_region.id_region = pos.id_region
WHERE balance.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND DATE_ADD('2014-02-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY location_region.id_region
ORDER BY money DESC
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is the query giving any error? What is not working on your query? Getting more than expected results?

Comment: Is taking around 5 seconds to comply, and in each row the SUM is bringing a way too higher value. Between all balances, the SUM is around 60k (select SUM(value) FROM balance)... but when executing the query above, the highest value is 716k.

Comment: on what field in `balance` table are you joining the remaining tables?

Comment: @Neels don't quite get your question. The only link between balance and location_region is: balance->user->pos->location_region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query has a logical error, JOIN condition between balance and user tables is incomplete (missing `balance.id_user`). So instead of `balance LEFT JOIN user ON user.id_user` you should have `balance LEFT JOIN user ON user.id_user=balance.id_user`. This is causing the JOINed table to have more rows (number of rows in balance times number of rows in user table). So the final SUM is bringing a way too higher value.

I tried the following query on your sample data (I changed some values) and it seems to be working fine:

```
SELECT location_region.name, SUM(balance.value) AS money
FROM balance
LEFT JOIN user USING(id_user)
LEFT JOIN pos USING(id_pos)
LEFT JOIN location_region USING(id_region)
WHERE balance.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND DATE_ADD('2014-02-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY location_region.id_region
ORDER BY money DESC
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dda28/3

Comment: Holy sh! Thanks for that. I really couldn't see it anymore. After several hours working one's mind just doesn't work like it should be. I'm off to work now, hopefully without bugs hehe. Thanks again Aziz!

Answer (score 0):

On having a detailed look at your table structure and the query that you gave, what I feel is this mismatch could happen because of duplicate number of rows that might be cropping up due to the `JOIN`. What I suggest in this case is to find the `DISTINCT` rows and summing it up so that you get an exact result. Now since `SUM DISTINCT` is not available in MySQL, you could try this different approach to accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT location_region.name, 
SUM(balance.value)*COUNT(DISTINCT id_user)/COUNT(id_user) AS money
FROM balance
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id_user = balance.id_user
LEFT JOIN pos ON pos.id_pos = user.id_pos
LEFT JOIN location_region ON location_region.id_region = pos.id_region
WHERE balance.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND DATE_ADD('2014-02-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY location_region.id_region
ORDER BY money DESC
```

In my comment, was wondering why u did not JOIN `user` table with `ON` clause as `user.id_user = balance.id_user`. I have added that however in my query. Hope this helps.

Comment: it returns the same value for all records: 4,564.314836

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle with some sample data?